# How can I link to the ID of a user's profile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two controllers- a `ProfilesController` and a `UsersController`. I have a page full of blog posts, and I want each to have a link to the *profile* of the user who created them. I've been having a wee problem with this lately, and I want to start fresh, but don't know where to begin. How can I go about this?

Post controller:

```
 def index
    @shit = Static.all.order('id DESC')
  if params[:search]
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  else
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end
 end
```

Profiles model:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Users model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  validates :username, uniqueness: true
  has_many :posts, foreign_key: :author
  has_many :comments, foreign_key: :author
  has_one :profile, foreign_key: :user

  after_create :build_profile

  def build_profile
    Profile.create(user: self) # Associations must be defined correctly for this syntax, avoids using ID's directly.
  end

end
```

> BTW not using Devise

Answer (score 0):

Use [`joins`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins)

```
def index
  @shit = Static.all.order('id DESC')
  scope = 
    if params[:search]
      Post.search(params[:search])
    else
      Post.all
    end

  @posts =
    scope.
      joins(:users).
      joins(:profiles).
      order("created_at DESC").
      paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In single `@post` object you should have relation to owner (user). In your view for each post  use route for user_path but provide it with `@post.user`

Example in view

`<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= link_to user_path(post.user) %>
    //Rest of post content
<% end %>`